# Deleting sub-element from JSON file

Tags: python, json

I thought it was simple to delete a key from JSON nested dict, but I end up with errors . 
I have JSON file as shown below, and want to delete a key `"8888"` from its element `"Codes"`.

dummy.json:

```
{
    "Codes": {
        "8888": "code1|18888",
        "9999": "code2|19999",
        "7777": "code3|17777"
    },
    "Names": {
        "Site1": "Site1|18888",
        "Site2": "Site2|19999",
        "Site3": "Site3|17777"
    }
}
```

Python code:

```
import json

with open('dummy.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    for element in data["Codes"]:
        #del element['8888']
        element.pop('8888', None)

with open('dummy.json'), 'w') as outfile:  
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Result:

For the first attempt, I tried `del element['8888']` and it throws `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item deletion`

As per example found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606930/delete-an-element-in-a-json-object/) I have tried with `element.pop('8888', None)` and it throws `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'` error.

I am not sure what mistake I did, please help.

Comment: ...are you saving the data again at all? You don't seem to.

Comment: @Tomalak, thanks for response, i have added next piece of code to write data into JSON file again,, But i dont think that is necessary since my code is failed at pop/delete element level.. if i misunderstand your question, please clarify.

Comment: What kind of data structure do you have after reading the file? Point is, your questions has nothing to do with JSON but everything with the use of that data structure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `for element in data["Codes"]` loop, element will be key of `data["Codes"]` dictionary. So if print all element of `data["Codes"]`, result is like this.

```
for element in data["Codes"]:
    print(element)
>>> 8888
>>> 9999
>>> 7777
```

You don't need for loop. If you want to delete(or pop) some key of `data["Codes"]`, just do like this.

```
data["Codes"].pop("8888", None)
```

Answer (score 2):

While iterating over `data["Codes"]`, `element` will be a key of the `data["Codes"]` dictionary and it's a string, which doesn't have a `pop` function (can be applied on dicts only).

Try instead:

```
import json
with open('dummy.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)
    data["Codes"].pop("8888")

with open('dummy.json', 'w') as outfile:  
    json.dump(data, outfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
with open('test.json') as fp:
    data = json.loads(fp.read())
    del data['Codes']['8888']
```