# Remove objects in nested json response python

Tags: python-3.x

This json file has nested "dbg_info","status","start_element","num_elements" etc as object.I want to recursively go through json and recursivily remove objects with the name mentioned in this list.["dbg_info","status","start_element","num_elements"].In python.

My Json:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "start_element": 0,
    "num_elements": 100,
   
        }
    ]
}
```

How to remove nested json elements?.I am not able to set the logic for the same.
Thankyou

Comment: the json you posted throwing the error while parsing

Comment: how about this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606930/delete-an-element-in-a-json-object

Comment: @pravinmishra still not working. are you able to parse the json you posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursive function

```
import json

d = json.loads(json_data)
lst = ["dbg_info","status","start_element","num_elements"]

def fun(d, lst=[]):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in list(d.items()):
            d.pop(k) if k in lst else fun(v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        map(fun, d)

fun(d, lst)
```

Comment: Thankyou very much.What should i pass in 'd' and function is not returning anything.

Comment: plus if last element is removed ',' will be present.

Comment: @pravinmishra updated the answer check now. and what last element why comma is important?

Comment: Got it but its returning none.

Comment: @pravinmishra there is no need of return the changes made in the function reflect in the dictionary `d` so need of `retutn`