# how to remove key/value pair in a json file in python

Tags: python, json

```js
{
    "duncan_long": {
        "id": "drekaner",
        "name": "Duncan Long",
        "favorite_color": "Blue"
    },
    "kelsea_head": {
        "id": "wagshark",
        "name": "Kelsea Head",
        "favorite_color": "Ping"
    },
    "phoenix_knox": {
        "id": "jikininer",
        "name": "Phoenix Knox",
        "favorite_color": "Green"
    },
    "adina_norton": {
        "id": "slimewagner",
        "name": "Adina Norton",
        "favorite_color": "Red"
    }
}
```

I am trying to Return a JSON list of all the users excluding the id of the user

Comment: d = json.loads(your_json); for k, v in d.items(): del v['id']; d[k] = v

Comment: Do you want to remove those items from the actual json file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Delete an element in a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606930/delete-an-element-in-a-json-object)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming, the file in which you have your JSON is called `file.json`:

```py
import json
with open('file.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    for key, value in d.items():
        del value['id']
        d[key] = value
```

Alternative you can use the following:

```py
import json
with open('file.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    for key, value in d.items():
        value.pop('id', None) // this will not crash if the element has no key 'id'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import json


with open('file.json') as fin:
    your_structure = json.load(fin)

for value in your_structure.values():
    value.pop('id', None)
```