# Why json has an erroe when deleted a list in replit

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, list

## Im trying to delete a single index in a list which is inside a json file

---

**the file**

```json
{
   "0": [
      "0",
      "1",
      "2",
      "3"
   ]
}
```

---

**The program**

```py
import json
with open("main.json","r") as jsonfile:
  jsonfile = json.load(jsonfile)
key = "0"

index = int(input("which index u want to remove: "))

with open("main.json","r+") as f:
  if key in jsonfile:
    #jsonfile[key].append(str(index))

    del jsonfile[key][index]
    
    json.dump(jsonfile,f,indent=3)
```

**This is how it looks after the programme deletes the index:**
[image: the]

**Please say how to stop this problem. Im using repl.it**

Comment: `r+` does not truncate the file. You have been overwriting the beginning but the end is left in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with saving your file. Firstly, use `"w"` not `"r+"` because you are not reading. Secondly, to save it, simply use:

```
f.write(json.dumps(jsonfile))
```

See: [Delete an element in a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606930/delete-an-element-in-a-json-object)

Comment: ok let me try thanks

Answer (score 3):

Change to "r+" to "w" to write the whole file again.

```
with open("main.json","w") as f:
  if key in jsonfile:
    #jsonfile[key].append(str(index))

    del jsonfile[key][index]

    json.dump(jsonfile,f,indent=3)
```

Answer (score -1):

The error is with the "r+" which should be "w":

```py
import json
with open("main.json","r") as jsonfile:
  jsonfile = json.load(jsonfile)
key = "0"

index = int(input("which index u want to remove: "))

with open("main.json","w") as f:
  if key in jsonfile:
    #jsonfile[key].append(str(index))

    del jsonfile[key][index]
    
    json.dump(jsonfile,f,indent=3)
```

Works on replit.com, I know because thats what I use.

Comment: The problem was is that r+ appends and is not the cleanest option.