# Delete specific data from JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file

**The idea:**

A JSON file should be loaded and the object `2-uID` with its sub-items should be deleted. The edited content should be saved in the same JSON file.

**The problem:**

I have already tried several approaches, like [this one from an SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606930/delete-an-element-in-a-json-object#answer-36607264), but nothing has worked for me yet.

The code shown does not delete anything, but pushes the content all into one line.

**The current code**

Python code:

```python
import json

with open("path/to/json") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for element in data:
    if '2-uID' in element:
        del element['2-uID']

with open("path/to/json", 'w') as data_file:
    data = json.dump(data, data_file)
```

JSON file:

```json
    {
    "uID": {
        "1-uID": {
            "username": "1-username",
            "pinned": true
        },
        "2-uID": {
            "username": "2-username",
            "pinned": false
        },
        "3-uID": {
            "username": "3-username",
            "pinned": false
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the JSON file should look like after the process:

```json
    {
    "uID": {
        "1-uID": {
            "username": "1-username",
            "pinned": true
        },
        "3-uID": {
            "username": "3-username",
            "pinned": false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Once a JSON formatted data is read by python,  it is stored as a list of dictionaries/lists. For your case, you can use `pop()` to delete a particular key. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11277432/how-can-i-remove-a-key-from-a-python-dictionary. Your example only deletes a copy of the key, not from the actual list of dictionaries/lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

This is your problem:

```py
for element in data:
    if '2-uID' in element:
        del element['2-uID']
```

`data` is the top-level element, so it only has one key: "uID". Try printing out "element" :)

---

Maybe I'm misundertanding you, but shouldn't you just use `del` ?

This works for me

```py
# string holding the JSON object
s = r"""{
    "uID": {
        "1-uID": {
            "username": "1-username",
            "pinned": true
        },
        "2-uID": {
            "username": "2-username",
            "pinned": false
        },
        "3-uID": {
            "username": "3-username",
            "pinned": false
        }
    }
}"""

import json

j = json.loads(s)

# remove one of the elements
del j["uID"]["2-uID"]

# see that the element is now gone
print(j)

# output:
# {'uID': {'2-uID': {'pinned': False, 'username': '2-username'},
#          '3-uID': {'pinned': False, 'username': '3-username'}}}
```

Comment: Does its job somehow - However (related to the JSON file) the content is written under the previous content. So I still have the old content with 2-uID and additionally in the same file the new content without 2-uID.

Comment: Then you need to check how you store to disk. Are you perhaps opening the file in "append"-mode? I have a feeling that the code you have posted, is a simplification of your actual code, no?

Comment: That is correct, the actual code is much larger. However, the question refers to a specific function that should also run independently. I open the file with r+, so the problem shouldn't come from that

Comment: Ugh, never mind, I was able to fix the exporting problem. I forgot to use "json.dump(j, delObj)" with "with open(path, "w") as jsonFile:".

Comment: @JueK3y glad you found a solution :) If two things are "wrong" simultaneously, it can be extremely difficult to diagnose the problem!